# Add in explicit representation of missing rows to data frame?

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

Assume I have a data frame

```
df <- tibble(name = c("Mark", "Frank"),
             value1 = c(3,7),
             value2 = c(8,2))

  name  value1 value2
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Mark       3      8
2 Frank      7      2
```

However, I know that there are missing names. Is there a way to fill in the rows of missing names with `NA`?

I would want to supply a vector such as

```
name_list <- c("Mark", "Frank", "Joe", "Bob", "Sam")
```

and obtain a data frame such as

```
  name  value1 value2
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Mark       3      8
2 Frank      7      2
3 Joe       NA     NA
4 Bob       NA     NA
5 Sam       NA     NA
```

I tried using `tidyr::complete()` but it didn't seem like it could be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try `full_join`

```
dplyr::full_join(df, data.frame(name = name_list))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  name  value1 value2
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Mark       3      8
2 Frank      7      2
3 Joe       NA     NA
4 Bob       NA     NA
5 Sam       NA     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe this following the sage solution from **@ThomasIsCoding**:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- name_list %>% data.frame() %>% setNames(.,'name') %>%
  left_join(df)
```

Output:

```
   name value1 value2
1  Mark      3      8
2 Frank      7      2
3   Joe     NA     NA
4   Bob     NA     NA
5   Sam     NA     NA
```

Or using `complete()`:

```
#Code2
newdf <- df %>% complete(data.frame(name=name_list))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  name  value1 value2
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Bob       NA     NA
2 Frank      7      2
3 Joe       NA     NA
4 Mark       3      8
5 Sam       NA     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `merge` from `base R`

```
merge(df, data.frame(name = name_list), all = TRUE)
```